# Fletcher-Reeves method (how to choose $\alpha$)

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods

I am implementing the Fletcher-Reeves method to minimize the Matyas function (https://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/matya.html).

Here's the algorithm I am following:

Initialize $\vec{x_0}$ with arbitrary values

(1) Evaluate $f_0$ as $f(\vec{x_0})$, $\nabla{f_0} = \nabla{f(\vec{x_0})}$

(2) Set $p_0 = -\nabla{f_0}, k=0$

(3) `While`  $\nabla{f_k} \ne 0$:
  Compute $\alpha_{k}$ and set $\vec{x_{k+1}} = \vec{x_k} + \alpha_{k}p_k$

etc.

I do not think it is necessary to include the whole description since what I cannot understand is the choice of $\alpha$.

It is further mentioned that the value of $\alpha$ should satisfy the strong Wolfe conditions:

$$f(x_k + \alpha_{k}p_{k}) \leq f(x_k) + c_1\alpha_{k}\nabla{f_k}^{T}p_k $$ 
$$|\nabla{f(x_k+\alpha_kp_k)^{T}p_k} \leq -c_2\nabla{f_k^{T}}p_k$$

for some $0<c_1<c_2<\frac{1}{2}$

Do I understand correctly, I can select the values of $c_1$ and $c_2$ and then iterate over a range of small values and check whether the value satisfies the requirements above. This approach should work, but I suspect there is something much more efficient than just brute-forcing.

Comment: @Moo, thank you. In that implementation, can you please elaborate on how to find $\lambda_k$ which minimizes $f (x_k -  \lambda_kv_k )$.

Comment: Yes, your second link seems to be describing the same algorithm. The book I am reading is quite popular so that doesn't come as a surprise (Nocedal, Right).

Comment: I wish I could say yes, but I am afraid that it's easier for me to understand this line search procedure mathematically rather than trying to understand his C code (I am not very familiar with C). Probably, you could answer my main question. Does it make sense to select some arbitrary value of $\alpha$ and just test it against the Wolfe conditions?